# Is there a good video for learning how to dual boot ubuntu and OS X

Tags: dual-boot, video, macosx

I am having trouble dual booting ubuntu and OS X with the written instructions. I was wondering if there was a good installation video that would guide me through the steps?

Answer (score 0):

A quick search on YouTube brought [this video](http://youtu.be/M7NX6qUKPwo) up as the first search result. I can't vouch for how helpful or accurate it is though (the person who made it mentions in the video that they are setting up a dual boot with Ubuntu 11.04, which is pretty old).

This is a rather subjective question anyway, since there could be plenty of video tutorials available online for this sort of thing and it would come down to personal preference on which one you feel is most informative and helpful.